# Changing the style within the ASP.Net Menu Control

Tags: asp.net, menu

I've been having a problem with my menu control with the drop down menu with the background color staying white, when I want it to be yellow. I've tried changing some of the properties options so that the BackColor would be "yellow", but it still persists to be white. I've noticed that the menu color without hovering over any links is yellow, but the drop down menu is white. This is what I have in the control:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" 
    BackColor="Yellow" EnableTheming="True" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StaticMenuStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
</asp:Menu>
```

The control is using a static view, but changing those BackColors didn't help much either.

Also, is it possible to remove those "Arrow" images beside each link that has a drop down list? I figure it has something to do with the style properties, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time, since the question has been asked, and I hope the asker would have got the answer by now. But I am adding one to it so as to help another guy out there.

Looking at the rendered html in Firebug, I assume the page lacks the CSS styles, neither internal nor inline. So, it is better that you add your own style for the menu.

You could try this (Add to internal or external style sheet linked with your aspx page):

```
/* #ctl00_Menu1 is the ID of my menu when rendered*/

#ctl00_Menu1 span
{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
#ctl00_Menu1 span a
{
    background: #1383dd;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
#ctl00_Menu1 span a:hover
{
    background: #0065b6;
    color: #fff;
}
```

hope it helps.